# Centering of text inside a button in android

Tags: android, xml

I have looked through stackoverflow and have seen some ppl have issues with centering text inside a button.  I have tried gravity, center, textAlignment, etc.. but so far nothing has worked.  Does anyone have any ideas on how I can fix this?  Thanks

This button is basically an button with a minus or - symbol in it but it won't put the - sign in the center.  I have tried this with + as well but no luck.  Any help is appreciated.

I can get the button to center the text but I have to use wrap_content for width and height. I do not want a button that big however. Would like it 40dp by 40dp

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button_minusMin"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit_minute"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:background="@drawable/button1"
            android:text="@string/button_minusMin"
            android:textAlignment="gravity"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

This is my button1 xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item><layer-list>
        <item android:right="5dp" android:top="5dp"><shape>
                <corners android:radius="3dp" />

                <solid android:color="#000000" />
            </shape></item>
        <item android:bottom="2dp" android:left="2dp"><shape>
                <gradient android:angle="270" android:endColor="#000000" android:startColor="#F06F14" />

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#BABABA" />

                <corners android:radius="4dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp" android:top="10dp" />
            </shape></item>
    </layer-list></item>
```

I have tried the following which works but wanted to have shading which is why I used button1.xml  Is something in my button1.xml throwing things off?

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/button_minusSets"
            android:layout_width="35dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/edit_sets"
            android:layout_marginLeft="55dp"
            android:background="#F06F14"
            android:text="@string/button_minusSets"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: You cannot center the symbol in button or TextView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try adding `android:gravity="center"` to your Button ?

Edit 1 : Adding Button XML

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@drawable/button_drawable"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="+" >
</Button>
```

Comment: Yes I did but it did not have any affect

Comment: I tested with the same selector you provided with the Button XML I just added. Works Fine.

Comment: try removing the text size from the button layout.

Comment: Nice!!  That worked... any ideas why?  or how I can increase the size of the - sign?  I guess I could import an image vice text..

Comment: Probably because the text size that you provided can't fit in the 35dp X 40dp dimensions.

Answer (score 1):

The fast answer (maybe not giving you the reason why your code isn't working, but still doing the job) would be to place this `Button` with a `TextView` in some sort of layout (e.g. [FrameLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout.html)) .

For example like this (insert your ids yourself please):

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/button1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="@string/button_minusSets"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="30sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

This gives you the centered text just like you wanted.

If I come up with the solution to the problem with your code, I'll write it in comments.

Answer (score 1):

inside class

```
button.setIncludeFontPadding(false);
```

inside XML

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```